# Another issue with strlen()

Tags: c, strlen

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen("word"); i++ );
    {
        printf("_");
        printf(" ");
    }
return 0;
}
```

I seem to have a problem again with strlen(). The for loop should print `"_ _ _ _ "` in this case as there are four letters in word. I'm guessing it's do with `strlen()` returning a `size_t` value. How to fix this problem? I tried to change `i` to from `int` to `size_t` but that did not seem to help.

Comment: What is the loop actually printing? Additionally, you should not use strlen as a loop condition - it is a slow, O(N) operation that will run in every loop step.

Comment: Do u like semicolon very much  ?

Comment: @missingno: being a string literal, any half-decent compiler (read: any) will optimise the call to `strlen` automatically.

Comment: @Jack: Not really - the compiler would need to know that strlen does not have any side-effects in order to pull it out of the loop and that is tricky to do since its an external function. Sure, its a standard library function but due to how C gets compiled and linked its actually a big hack to optimize it like that!

Comment: @missingno: just take any decent compiler and check assembly. It will get optimized away. Actually with a string literal `strlen` function won't be called at all. Try with `strlen("foobar")` and you will see that the compiler will directly use the value with no calls to `strlen`. `movl $6, %ebx LBB1_1: decl %ebx jne LBB1_1`

Comment: @Jack: I'm just pointing out that its a fragile optimization since it depends on cross-module optimization (something thats actually tricky in C) - while this particular example might be optimized, things that are very similar to it might not! Additionally, I'm not a big fan of writing code where the asymptotic time complexity depends on compiler optimizations.

Comment: @missingno: and I'm not a fan of premature optimization in situations that are not proved to be a bottleneck for the current implementation or that doesn't require performance at all. That's why I pointed out that this example will be optimised almost certainly. We should be fans of writing code that relies on optimisation since they're smarter than both of us and will do all the dirty work without messing the readability of what we write :)

Comment: @missingno It takes no cross-module optimization to optimize calls to standard functions. The glibc manual for instance says “The names of all library types, macros, variables and functions that come from the ISO C standard are reserved unconditionally; your program may not redefine these names”. If you cannot redefine `strlen`, the compiler is free to assume that `strlen` is the standard `strlen`, and it does.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you have a semicolon AFTER the for. So your code calls `strlen()` four times.

```
for (i = 0; i < strlen("word"); i++ ) --> ; <--
```

Then it calls printf twice, independently of the loop.

```
int main()
{
    size_t i, len = strlen("word");
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        printf("_ ");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

"strlen" is not cheap - it has to hand-count the the chars-until-'\0' in the string supplied it, and using it in a loop iterator will cause it to be called every iteration of the loop.

The above variant captures the value once at the start of the loop and compares against the result making it a one time calculation.

Comment: int main(void)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int len = strlen("word");
    for ( i=0;  i < len; ++i) {
        printf("_ ");
    }

    return 0;
}

Your code didn't work but now this works! Thanks!

Comment: @user2955782: You should post the compiler error message instead of saying "unknown reason". Anyway, your compiler is probably compiling against the older ANSI C standard that does not allow for variable declarations inside for-loop conditions.

Comment: One of the problems with tagging a question as both C++ and C is that the two languages are not the same. I've edited the answer to work in C.

Comment: Here's a live demo on ideone: http://ideone.com/ga7G5p or the C++ variant http://ideone.com/K5iu7J

Comment: Yea that seems to be it. It says taht you can only deeclare variables inside for loops in C99 mode